# Find $E(X\mid Y)$ if $Y$ is beta and $X$ conditionally on $Y$ is geometric with parameter $Y$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

> Let be $Y$ Beta$(\alpha, \beta )$ distributed random variable. Further more let $X$ conditional on $\{Y=y \}$ geometric distributed with paramter $y$.
>   I want to determine $\mathbb E( X\mid \sigma(Y))$.

My attempt,
$$\int_{0}^{1}x f(x\mid y)\,dx= \int_{0}^{1} x(1-(1-y)^xy\, dx =\int_{0}^{1}x \, dx - \int_{0}^{1}(1-y)^{x+1}y\, dx$$ and we now $\int^{1}_0(1-y)^{x+1}y$ is beta distributed.Does this approach make sense? Help is much appreciated. Especially I am not sure about the borders aswell.

Comment: What is $\sigma(Y)$?

Comment: @expiTTpz0 I suspect the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$.

Comment: @drhab What does conditioning over a sigma algebra even mean? I don't understand.

Comment: @expiTTpz0 [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Measure-theoretic_formulation) might help.

Comment: @expiTTpz0 the sigma algebra generated by Y

Comment: @drhab so my borders are wrong? But this is the correct way?

Comment: Hint: find an expression for $g(y)=\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y=y]$ and then find $\mathbb{E}[g(Y)]$

Comment: @Henry Is not my above approach exactly $\mathbb E[X \mid Y=y] ?$

Comment: @Henry The question asks for $E(X\mid Y)$. How can finding $E(g(Y))$ with $g(y)=E(X\mid Y=y)$, even help?

Comment: @expiTTpz0 "What does conditioning over a sigma algebra even mean? I don't understand." Good opportunity to learn the subject then, no?

Comment: Hints: Among the hypotheses you were given, the distribution of $Y$ is irrelevant to compute $E(X\mid Y)$. Furthermore, you might want to realize that $X$ is *discrete* hence approaches based on the existence of some PDF of $X$ are doomed from the start.

Comment: @JohnDoe if you want to just find $E[X \mid Y = y]$, why not just recognize that by definition, $X$ conditioned on $Y = y$ is geometric with parameter $y$ hence $E[X \mid Y] = (1-y)/y$? Or are you specifically looking for a measure-theoretic approach to the problem?

Comment: @Did Yes. I haven't yet read the measure theoretic approach to probability.

Comment: @Slug Pue actaully just a solution. For me your comment makes sense

Comment: @expiTTpz0 Why your two first comments then?

Comment: @Did I wanted to clarify if $\sigma(Y)$ is some common notation that OP is using that I might not be aware of.

Comment: @expiTTpz0 Quite canonical, yes.